# django-oauth-toolkit setup without Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, oauth-2.0

I have a web project made with Django 1.9 which will have its RESTful API as an application. I don't want to use Django Rest Framework since, from my understanding, it works as a wrapper of Django itself, which I already have.

I'm using django-oauth-toolkit for OAuth2 authentication, but the problem is that Django requires the csrf token in POST requests and I wan't to disable the SessionAuthenticationMiddleware in all the application. I tried to redirect to an extended method for the TokenView class, but Django still asks for the csrf token in the request.

Here is what I have so far:

Project Structure:

```
myproject:
  |_app1
  |_app2
  |_api
      |_views.py
      |_urls.py
```

api/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^o/token/$', views.TokenView.as_view(), name="token"),
    url(                                              
        r'^o/',
        include(
            'oauth2_provider.urls',
            namespace='oauth2_provider'
        )
    ),  # OAuth2 Provider
]
```

api/views.py:

```
class TokenView(InitialTokenView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TokenView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TokenView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The TokenView class comes from the original code of django-oauth-toolkit https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/views/base.py

What is what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.